# Read a plain text file with php

Tags: php, file, text

I have a text file with this information in my server:

```
Data1
Data2
Data3
.
.
.
DataN
```

How do I read all the information from the text file (line by line) using PHP?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
<?php

$fh = fopen('filename.txt','r');
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
  // <... Do your work with the line ...>
  // echo($line);
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

This will give you a line by line read.. read the notes at [php.net/fgets](http://www.php.net/fgets) regarding the end of line issues with Macs.

Answer (score 27):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

`$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents($filename));`

This wont actually read it line by line, but it will get you an array which can be used line by line.  There are a number of alternatives.

Comment: I assume this will "explode" your memory with a very large dataset

Answer (score 16):

```
$filename = "file.txt";
$lines = array();
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");

if(filesize($filename) > 0){
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
    $lines = explode("\n", $content);
    fclose($fp);
}

print_r($lines);
```

In this code full content of the file is copied to the variable `$content` and then split it into an array variable `$lines` with each newline character in the file.

Answer (score 15):

You can also produce array by using file:

```
$array = file('/path/to/text.txt');
```

Comment: This is handy, but note: each line has new line character at end :D

Answer (score 5):

W3Schools is your friend: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgets.asp

And here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php has more info on fopen including what the modes are.

**What W3Schools says:**

```
<?php
$file = fopen("test.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  echo fgets($file). "<br />";
  }

fclose($file);
?>
```

fopen opens the file (in this case test.txt with mode 'r' which means read-only and places the pointer at the beginning of the file)

The while loop tests to check if it's at the end of file (feof) and while it isn't it calls fgets which gets the current line where the pointer is.

Continues doing this until it is the end of file, and then closes the file.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
$filename = 'file.txt';

$data = file($filename);
foreach ($data as $line_num=>$line)
{
    echo 'Line # <b>'.$line_num.'</b>:'.$line.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$file="./doc.txt";
$doc=file_get_contents($file);

$line=explode("\n",$doc);
foreach($line as $newline){
    echo '<h3 style="color:#453288">'.$newline.'</h3><br>';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless specifically defining where and how to handle the string, simply use **file_get_contents()**. No need for long blocks of iteration and workarounds.

For example, reading version from **latestversion.txt** in /client/ with a fallback using a ternary operator (condition ? do : else)

```
$version = file_exists("client/latestversion.txt") ? file_get_contents("client/latestversion.txt") : "0.0.0.0";
```

Here, we are confirming latestversion.txt *does* exist, and requesting to read it, otherwise output "0.0.0.0". Its a one-liner that gets the job done.

Then you simply echo out

```
echo "The version is: " . $version;
```

Or you can call it like this

```
printf("The version is: %s", $version);
```

Cleansing the string at this point would be advised depending on the access permissions to that file if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

> You can read a group of txt files in a folder and echo the contents like this.

```
 <?php
$directory = "folder/";
$dir = opendir($directory);
$filenames = [];
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
$filename = $directory . $file;
$type = filetype($filename);
if($type !== 'file') continue;
$filenames[] = $filename;
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$aa = fopen('a.txt','r');
echo fread($aa,filesize('a.txt'));

$a = fopen('a.txt','r');
while(!feof($a)){echo fgets($a)."<br>";}
fclose($a);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: ...David's comment is especially important if a question already contains a lot of answers. Adding a new one is fine, as long as it contains some new insights

Answer (score 0):

$your_variable = file_get_contents("file_to_read.txt");

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

The code posted above from Payload works great. I'd like to add something to this because others might run into the same problem. I used your code and was trying to compare a value with a $line that was fetched from the .txt file. Even though I know my keyword matches a line I kept getting an error. this is an example of the code...

```
textfile.txt content example:

text1
text2
keyword
text3
```

---

```
$keyword = 'keyword';

while($line = fgets($txt_file)) {

    if (substr_compare($line, $keyword, 0) === 0) { 
        $value = $line;
    }
}

echo $value; // returns nothing because the if statement was false
```

The problem is each $line is carrying a new line at the end of it. But in my case I just used enter for a new line when creating the .txt file, it's not specified with something like "\n" or idk "\r\n".  Anyways, if you're running into the same problem be sure to trim() the $line before you work with it to get rid of any whitespace or in this case the new line or you might keep running into errors. the shortest and easiest way to do this without getting weird results is to simply trim it right in the while statement like this...

```
while($line = trim(fgets($txt_file))) {
    
    if (substr_compare($line, $keyword, 0) === 0) { 
        $value = $line;
    }
} 

echo $value; // result: keyword
```

and yes i did get some weird results trying to throw the trim() around $line inside the substr_compare() function, even though the if statement result was TRUE the $value would have a result of " keyword " with a space on the beginning and end of the keyword.  weird stuff...