# Resource ID #2?

Tags: php

Why when it displays does it say `Resource id #2`?

All I am doing is fetching a simple number (0) out of a `.txt` file:

```
$num = fopen('qnum/qnum.txt', 'r'); 
echo $num;
```

Comment: There's nothing to "fix".  When you open a file, you get a file handle, which you can use for subsequent "fread()" or "fgets()".  You're just echo'ing the handle.  Look here for a good example of opening and reading your file: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Comment: BTW, what does this question have to do with MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

You are not actually *reading* the file. You are only [opening](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) it and acquiring a reference to the file. You have to add more code (e.g. something along the lines of the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4103287/507519) question) to read the contents of the file.