# PHP fopen and is_dir issue

Tags: php

I have a small page to check if a network share is up. To do so, the user can had a share in a txt file (easier than touching the code itself) and then the page will read the text file and check if its online or not.

But the probleme is, it doesn't work has expected. looks like it work only when I have 1 line in the text file

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("share.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
 while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    echo $line;
    if (is_dir($line)) {echo $line ."is up";}
    else {echo $line ."is down";}
 }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
echo "No text file has been found";}
```

?>

and my share.txt contain

```
\\server1\folder 
\\server2\folder 
\\server3\folder
```

In that case, the page return only the last share as up and not all 3.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Hello Friends see this link:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103287/read-a-plain-text-file-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if the line endings are not correctly recognised by PHP. In this case it should help to activate the

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
```

so that PHP will also deal correctly with the "\r" line ending for example.

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#107333) comment for more information.