# PHP readfile() printing issue

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to read a local text file in PHP, and I have the line of code so that it does read the file, however it echos it when I don't want it to?
`$teacher1department = readfile("dir/test.txt");`
I want that to save as a variable so I can use it later, however it instantly prints it to the screen? How would I fix this error?

Comment: Warning: fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/www.exmaple.com/dir/index.php on line 16

Comment: Did you try reading the PHP documentation of `readfile()`? It says: **Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.**

Comment: If you then go down to the **See Also** section you'll see a link to the function you want.

Comment: **`file_get_contents()` - Reads entire file into a string**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a plain text file with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103287/read-a-plain-text-file-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$teacher1department = file_get_contents("dir/test.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept your answer in 3 mins when it lets me