# How to get a line in a txt file and echo it out?

Tags: php, html

I have a txt file containing some temperatures:

```
26 C  
25.06 C  
25.00 C  
25.00 C  
25.00 C  
25.00 C  
24.94 C  
24.94 C  
24.94 C  
24.94 C  
24.94 C  
24.94 C
```

And I want those lines to be echo out in a table in my php/html file:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>TEMP</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>TEMP</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

How I do this?

Comment: Parse the file and insert them in an array. Then call it in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a plain text file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103287/read-a-plain-text-file-with-php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php you can do that playing with flags

Comment: Thanks for helping I'll try it and will let you know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide any example data for how you get the Date and Time, but given your `temps.txt`

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>TEMP</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php
foreach (file('temps.txt') as $temp) {
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>$temp</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

If your file also contains date/time information, then you might be interested in using a CSV format with [`fgetcsv`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)