# Import data from TXT to table in HTML with PHP

Tags: php, file, import

I must import file (example of this file in attachment) from .txt file to table in html (with 5 columns) to PHP document. I want to except the first column, whic added now to my table (Lp. and numbers from 1 ... xx) and the first line (it's the headers of column but not in my table - it's column in txt file and I don't want to import this).

Now my code is:

```
            <?php
            $file = fopen("test.txt","r");
            if(count >= 30);
            while(! feof($file))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                $line = fgets($file);
                $cols = explode('|', trim($line, '|'));
                $deleted_item = array_pop($cols);                   
                foreach($cols as $col)
                    echo "<td>$col</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            fclose($file);
        ?>
```

I need read and import data for example from 10 to 50 line from .txt file.

Example of file on Pastebin: pastebin.com/4045z1us

Image with what I want to have :)

[PICTURE WITH EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WiuP.png)

Thanks for help.

Comment: This is not a site where people write code for you, this is a Q'n'A. If you have a specific proble, you should edit your question so it contains that specific problem (but do be sure to use search before that, as your question is very likely already answered).

Comment: Search before asking a question. There are loads of resources online. A tutorial site would probably be more suitable. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103287/read-a-plain-text-file-with-php. Read php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Thanks :) I found the resolution (in 80% percent). I need to delete a Lp. column from file and with this code theres added the last, empty small column to my table. Anybody can help? 

Code: https://pastebin.com/6X3weRxN
How it's see: https://imgur.com/a/DsamF

Comment: @PawełG.- please don't host code externally, as overtime links can expire - please edit the question and add the code in there.

Answer (score 0):

To remove last item from an array, you can use [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Edited

```
$linecount = 0;     
while(! feof($file))
     {
        $linecount++;
        /* if line number is greater than 199 and the first 
        character is a + sign stop. The check for plus sign
        is to cover both 200 lines and 400 lines scenario
        */
        if (preg_match("/^\+/", $line) && $linecount > 199)
            break;

        //ignore until you read line 19
        if ($linecount < 19)
            continue;

        echo "<tr>";
        $line = fgets($file);
        $cols = explode('|', trim($line, '|'));

        // only print array items with index 1 to 5  
        foreach (range(1,5) as $i)
            echo "<td>$cols[$i]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

You need to pick up a good php book or go through some tutorials. As a matter of fact, I believe you should start with basics of control structures. With previous code, you should have been able to work this out easily.

Comment: Working perfect! You can help to delete the first column and the first line from importing file? (I do not want to import this to my table).

Comment: Set a counter, to keep track of number of lines. [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) removes the first item. I updated the answer.

Comment: The code in the answer, skips line 1 of your text file, then removes the first and last element before adding it to the table. With that answer you should be able to work the rest out.

Comment: thank you. I modify code but without effect which I want -> https://pastebin.com/1NbZZNvU

Comment: Maybe the text file is not formatted the way you think it is. Can you paste the first 3 -4 lines of your  text file.

Comment: Theres it https://pastebin.com/4045z1us - I want to cut the first 17 lines from it (it's always the same) and the last 20 lines (because file can have 200 lines or 400 so I can't have code with for example cut the lines after e.g. >= 200 line.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: With this code I have still first line with text headers and the empty lines with frame in the end of table.

Comment: I have provided more than a guideline. I trust you could use simple arithmetic to work out line numbers. Good luck.