# How do I get every line from a text file and put it in a website table?

Tags: php, html, str-replace, explode

I have a text file while contains a variable amount of lines and each line contains 3 things, an IP, browser info and a date. Basically it's a visitor log that contains these things.

I want to take a line, get each seperate part and replace rows in a html documents table. As of now I'm only able to get the first line from the file.

When I tried to just print something in the while loop that goes through each line to see if it actually goes through it multiple times it doesn't. It only echos the one time, it goes one lap and reads one line and then stops.

Text file contains for example:

- 2019/02/12 02:32:56--Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36--::1
- 2019/02/12 02:32:58--Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36--::1
- 2019/02/12 02:33:02--Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36--::1

Date, browser info and IP.

```
<?php
// file path
$path = './visitors.txt';
$html = file_get_contents("log.html");

$visitor_log = fopen($path, 'r');
if(flock($visitor_log, LOCK_SH)){
  // Loop genom alla rader i visitors.txt
  while (($line = fgets($visitor_log)) !== false) {
    $html_pieces = explode("<!--==xxx==-->", $html, 3); 
    $string_split = explode("--", $line, 3); 
    $html = str_replace("---date---", $string_split[0], $html); 
    $html = str_replace("---browser---", $string_split[1], $html); 
    $html = str_replace("---ip---", $string_split[2], $html); 
  }
  fclose($visitor_log);
}else{
die("Error! Couldn't read from file.");
}
echo $html;
?>
```

I have no idea why the loop doesn't go through the entire file. Is there a way to just echo every line to see if it can actually read all lines?

**EDIT:** I just tried

```
echo $html;
```

in the while loop and it prints out the first line three times so I believe it goes through all three lines but it doesn't get the new data. Does it have something to do with:

```
$html = file_get_contents("log.html");
```

not getting updated?

**EDIT:** html code for the table

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="left">Dare</th>
      <th align="left">Browser</th>
      <th align="left">IP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!--==xxx==-->
    <tr>
      <td align="left">---date---</td>
      <td align="left">---browser---</td>
      <td align="left">---ip---</td>
    </tr>
    <!--==xxx==-->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a plain text file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103287/read-a-plain-text-file-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you are adding data to your `$html`:

```
$html = str_replace("---date---", $string_split[0], $html);
```

This will replace every instance of `---date---` in your `$html` string with the date of the line currently being processed.  If `$html` is a single row template, that means it is converted into a row of data for the first line.  That will work fine.

But for the next line, the substitution strings `---date---` etc do not appear in `$html` any more - `$html` now includes your line 1 data.  So the `str_replace()` doesn't find anything to replace, and won't actually do anything, and you'll never see anything except the first line.

The best solution would be to keep your template and the generated results separate:

```
$html = file_get_contents("log.html");

// Split up your html into header, data row, and the bottom
$html_pieces = explode("<!--==xxx==-->", $html, 3); 

// Show the table header
echo $html_pieces[0];

$path = './visitors.txt';
$visitor_log = fopen($path, 'r');

while (($line = fgets($visitor_log)) !== false) {
    $string_split = explode("--", $line, 3); 

    // Generate a new line of $output from the data row of your $html_pieces
    $output = str_replace("---date---", $string_split[0], $html_pieces[1]); 
    $output = str_replace("---browser---", $string_split[1], $output); 
    $output = str_replace("---ip---", $string_split[2], $output); 

    // And display, line-by-line
    echo $output;
}

// All done, finish off your table
echo $html_pieces[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you ought to be able to read the text file like this perhaps. Using `file` to open the text file puts the contents into an array which is then easy to loop through and using `list` combined with `explode` makes it easy to generate variables. I couldn't really determine what the code was actually dong above as there seems to be no output and couldn't understand where `log.html` fitted in but hopefully this might help. ( not tested )

```
$textfile = './visitors.txt';
$lines = file( $textfile, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );

foreach( $lines as $line ){
    list( $date, $useragent, $ip )=explode( '--', $line );
    echo $date,$useragent,$ip,'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it!

The problem was

```
$html = file_get_contents("log.html");
```

and

```
echo $html;
```

Both lines have to be in the while loop.

Comment: Great you solved it. If `log.html` is not changing, there's no need to re-read it for every line of data though, you're just hammering your disk for nothing.  See my answer for a way to avoid that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I just realised that I am reading the table table head once for every line, is there a way to only write out table head once on the top and then print out every row? I added my html code above.

Comment: So your `log.html` includes a set of headings, and a blank template row?  Can you add it to your question?  Ah, you just did :-) Let me have a look.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  You were already partway there with your `$html_pieces `.

Comment: It works but my output is all messed up, it doesn't put it in the table and the header doesn't show check image: https://gyazo.com/05a9a5d15795ab9d8f85985b18aed5b5

Comment: I had a typo in the first version of my code, and edited it a few times - are you using the latest?  If yes, what does the generated source you are seeing look like? That should give a clue about what is wrong.

Comment: You're a PHP genie, I tried your code and it works perfectly.

Comment: :-) Glad it helped.