# How to replace text of cities on webpages from a file on FTP, where I have all cities

Tags: javascript, php

I want to generate text into websites based on some conditions.
I will create about 100 HTML pages with some text, but there will be some parts of text that will change based on different city.

I need something (maybe some call of javascript) to grab the specific city for webpage from a file or script.

For example:
This will be applied in H1 headline:

```
Page 1: domain.com/new-york

<h1>Cleaning services - New York</h1>


Page 2: domain.com/boston

<h1>Cleaning services - Boston</h1>
```

But the words "New York" and "Boston" will be grabbed somehow from file or you can suggest :)

[Image: How I think this should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Wcx.jpg)

Thx for suggestions.

Comment: Is there any way to introduce a database into this?

Comment: In order to read the file on your server, you would (for example) need PHP. Keep in mind that your server need to be capable to run PHP and also you need a .php file instead of .html. This SO link should help you to read a file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103287/read-a-plain-text-file-with-php -- @Chris Haas This looks like he is just beginning to learn stuff like this. So introducing a database at this stage would be even more confusing. (just my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify by URL parameters, the simplest way is this

```
<?php
$url= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$u = parse_url($url);
var_dump(explode('/', $u['path'])[1]);
```

If you want to be a little more sophisticated - there are dozens of open source tools that will help you a little more in recognizing the URL.

Comment: Thx man, but I think this is something different than my problem. Anyway I have just resolved that. Thx

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours, I have just resolved that!

new-york.php

```
<h1>Cleaning services <?php include 'vars.php';echo "$x1";?></h1>
```

boston.php

```
<h1>Cleaning services <?php include 'vars.php';echo "$x2";?></h1>
```

vars.php

```
<?php

$x1 = 'New York';
$x2 = 'Boston';

?>
```